# Scriptish and Multiple Iterations of the Script Launching

Tags: firefox, javascript

```
// ==UserScript==
// @id             rtskincruff
// @name           Right Gmail
// @version        1.0
// @namespace      OK
// @author         Exaskryz
// @description    
// @include        https://mail.google.com/*
// @run-at         window-load
// ==/UserScript==
//I tried for the @run-at document-end and document-idle
var colored = setInterval(function () {coloring()}, 10000);

function coloring() {
console.log("ping");
var name = document.getElementsByClassName("gb_l gb_n");
console.log("got name");
console.log(name.length);
if (name[0].innerHTML = "+Exaskryz") {
    name[0].style.color = "#FF0000";
    name[0].style.fontSize = "xx-large";
    name[0].innerHTML = "WRONG ACCOUNT TO SEND EMAIL FROM";
    //var backg = document.getElementsByClassName("AO");
    //backg[0].style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    } else if (name[0].innerHTML = "WRONG ACCOUNT TO SEND EMAIL FROM") {
    clearInterval(colored);
    alert("pun");
    }
```

The script is being launched 5 times and I can't figure out why or how to stop the other instances. The other instances seem to never be able to find any element with a class name (`gb_l gb_n`) and report back to me a `name.length` of `0`. It's also really weird because it will only ever get up to the part where it logs the `name.length` and never does any other `console.log` *UNLESS* it did get a value for the variable name.

Here's the full script with the full mess of trying to figure out how to stop this script from running every 10 seconds (originally had it set at 1 second):

```
    // ==UserScript==
    // @id             rtskincruff
    // @name           Right Gmail
    // @version        1.0
    // @namespace      OK
    // @author         Exaskryz
    // @description    
    // @include        https://mail.google.com/*
    // @run-at         document-idle
    // ==/UserScript==

    var colored = setInterval(function () {coloring()}, 10000);

    function coloring() {
    console.log("ping");
    var name = document.getElementsByClassName("gb_l gb_n");
    console.log("got name");
    console.log(name.length);
    if (name[0].innerHTML = "+Exaskryz") {
        name[0].style.color = "#FF0000";
        name[0].style.fontSize = "xx-large";
        name[0].innerHTML = "WRONG ACCOUNT TO SEND EMAIL FROM";
        //var backg = document.getElementsByClassName("AO");
        //backg[0].style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
        } else if (name[0].innerHTML = "WRONG ACCOUNT TO SEND EMAIL FROM") {
        clearInterval(colored);
        alert("pun");
        }
    console.log("passed first if");
        if (name.length>0) {
            if (name[0].innerHTML = "+Exaskryz") {
                name[0].style.color = "#FF0000";
                name[0].style.fontSize = "xx-large";
                name[0].innerHTML = "WRONG ACCOUNT TO SEND EMAIL FROM";
                //var backg = document.getElementsByClassName("AO");
                //backg[0].style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
            alert("bun");
            clearInterval(colored);
            alert("done");
            }
        }
    console.log("passed second if");
    var nong = document.getElementsByClassName("gb_K gb_ka gb_n gb_ga");
    console.log("got nong");
    alert(nong.length);
    if (nong[0].innerHTML = "CorrectAccount@gmail.com") {
        alert("hun");
       clearInterval(colored);
       alert("done");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but it may be possible that your script is also running on any iframes present at mail.google.com. To stop the script from running on iframes, there's two options.

In the meta data block of the script, you can set @noframes to true.

```
// @noframes true
```

Or, you can check at the beginning of the script whether or not the script's window is in fact the 'top most' window.

```
if (window != window.top) { return; }
```